# Dynamic text length of two textblocks to fit longlistselector

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I got this longlistselector which contains a header and a description text which are both dynamic.
I want it to scale so the description text wraps if it goes outside the width of the longlist selector.

The below image demostrates the issue pretty well:

[image]

How I want to to work:

[image]

And the code I got now:

```
                <Infrastructure:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding TrackingInformationItems}" Width="480">
                <Infrastructure:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <templates:ListboxTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
                            <templates:ListboxTemplateSelector.HeaderAndBody>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Width="480" MaxWidth="480" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,5" Visibility="{Binding Body, Converter={StaticResource EmptyStringConverter}}">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Style="{StaticResource TextboxLabelStyle}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </templates:ListboxTemplateSelector.HeaderAndBody>
                        </templates:ListboxTemplateSelector>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Infrastructure:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </Infrastructure:LongListSelector>
```

Any suggestion how I can accomplish this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm that there is no [RichTextBlockOverflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextblockoverflow(v=vs.95).aspx) in WP ?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed your `StackPanel` in a `Grid` and apply your `Width` to it instead to invoke your `TextWrapping` but like Tonio pointed out it would place your Body under your Header if there's not enough room since its in a `StackPanel` however you could do something more like this;

```
<TextBlock MaxWidth="480" Margin="0,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Visibility="{Binding Body, Converter={StaticResource EmptyStringConverter}}">
   <Run Text="{Binding Header}" Foreground="Blue"/>
   <Run Text="{Binding Body}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Humm i think it's not exactly the answer... If you look the description text part you can see that it's goes below the header part or your solution the description part stay below the description part. I think you can play with [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.documents.run(v=vs.95).aspx) if the header Style is simple.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, he always wants it to have it start on the side of the header, than ya. will update the answer.

Comment: Ok i delete mine in this case ?